# Calling .subscribe() after .pipe(); not executing my redirection code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have an `AuthService` with these methods:

```
signUp = (data: SignUp): Observable<AuthResponseData> => {
  const endpoint = `${env.authBaseUrl}:signUp?key=${env.firebaseKey}`;
  return this._signInOrSignUp(endpoint, data);
};

signIn = (data: SignIn): Observable<AuthResponseData> => {
  const endpoint = `${env.authBaseUrl}:signInWithPassword?key=${env.firebaseKey}`;
  return this._signInOrSignUp(endpoint, data);
};

private _signInOrSignUp = (endpoint: string, data: SignIn | SignUp): Observable<AuthResponseData> => {
  return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(endpoint, {
    ...data,
    returnSecureToken: true
  }).pipe(
    catchError(error => this._throwError(error)),
    tap(response => this._createAndEmitUserSubject(response)),
  );
}

private _throwError = error => {
  const errorMessage = error.error.error.message;
  return throwError(errorMessage);
};

private _createAndEmitUserSubject = (response: AuthResponseData) => {
  const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + +response.expiresIn * 1000);
  const user = new User(
    response.idToken,
    response.email,
    response.idToken,
    expirationDate
  );

  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  this.user$.next(user);
};
```

And in the sign-in and sign-up components, I call the those in following way:

```
submit = (): void => {
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  this.authService
    .signIn(this.loginForm.value)
    .subscribe({
      next: () => this.router.navigate(["/recipes"]),
      error: error => this.error = error
    });
};
```

But the code within `next` is not executed. If I remove `.pipe()` it is. I was hoping I did not need to use `.pipe()` in two places.

Comment: maybe `_createAndEmitUserSubject` errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `this._throwError` doesn't throw an error. If it was, `next` couldn't be called later. You are probably not `throw`'ing error in it and instead returning some value that goes into `next`

Comment: I do not think that is an issue, catch is not triggered when he removed the pipe, why will it be triggered on adding it

Comment: I updated the question to show the other methods. This one is returning `throwError` from `rxjs`. I tried throwing, but the issue persisted.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. @fermoga Try to switch  places `catchError` and `tap` to notice difference

Comment: @SOverfow sadly, nothing changed.

Comment: Commenting the line where `this.user$.next(user)` is, all works normally. `user$` is a `Subject`, and I now realize this is not necessary at all! But I'd like to know why it blocked the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `this.user$.next(user)` solves it, and I did't realize I did not need this at all, but I'd like to know why it blocked the flow.

```
private _createAndEmitUserSubject = (response: AuthResponseData) => {
  // ...

  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
};
```